# function not working Argument is missing with no default in r

Tags: r, function

below is the function i am trying to use.

it requires the package rv to run.

i am loading a .csv file. 
my data is as follows:

```
BMin 103
Fatal 0
SmpHrKm 47.05
ExpFac  588.61
aPriExp 0.13
bPriExp 0.25
aPriCPr 2.31
bPriCPr 396.69
```

when i run the code i get "Error in simfatal(data) : argument "SmpHrKm" is missing, with no default"

what am i doing wrong??

```
  simfatal <- function(BMin=-1, Fatal=-1, SmpHrKm, ExpFac, aPriExp=1, bPriExp=1,aPriCPr=1, bPriCPr=1)

   # BMin or (k):     observed number of bird minutes
# Fatal:    annual avian fatalities on an operational wind facility
# SmpHrKm or (w):  total time and area surveyed for bird minutes
# ExpFac or (ε):   expansion factor
# aPriExp:  alpha parameter for the prior on lambda
# bPriExp:  beta parameter for the prior on lambda
# aPriCPr:  alpha parameter for the prior on C
# bPriCPr:  beta parameter for the prior on C

# The default of a negative value for BMin or Fatal indicates that no data were collected for those model inputs

require(rv)

# Update the exposure prior 
 if(BMin>=0){
   aPostExp <- aPriExp + BMin
   bPostExp <- bPriExp + SmpHrKm
  }else{
   aPostExp <- aPriExp
   bPostExp <- bPriExp}

 Exp <- rvgamma(n=1, aPostExp, bPostExp)

# Update the collisions prior
 if(Fatal>=0){
  aPostCPr <- aPriCPr + Fatal
  bPostCPr <- ((rvmean(Exp) * ExpFac) - Fatal) + bPriCPr
 }else{

      aPostCPr <- aPriCPr
      bPostCPr <- bPriCPr}

     CPr <- rvbeta(n=1, aPostCPr, bPostCPr)

     Fatalities             <- ExpFac * Exp * CPr
     attr(Fatalities,"Exp") <- c(Mean=rvmean(Exp), SD=rvsd(Exp))
     attr(Fatalities,"CPr") <- c(Mean=

rvmean(CPr), SD=rvsd(CPr))

 return(Fatalities)} enter code here
```

Comment: Please post an example function call. You are probably not directly specifying what smphrkm should be when you call the function.

Comment: I guess when you read your csv the first column becomes a factor.

Comment: You may also want to try `SmpHrKm = SmpHrKm` in your function definition.

Comment: Hey Jul; excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean by "function call"